# Bootstrap panel increase panel-body size to fixed length with scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4, panel

Creating a panel in bootstrap with max, min length. I am trying to increase the length of panel body to a fix length. If the text overflows the length I would use the scroll bar.

increasing the length will also help be increase the border of the body. How do I do it, i tried using min-height and max-height but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
     <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                 <h4 class="generate-logs">LOGS</h4>
             </div>
                    <div class="panel-body" style="min-height: 10; max-height: 10;overflow-y: scroll;">
                            Step 1: <br> Step 2: <br> Step 3: <br> step 4: <br> Step 5:`enter code here`
                    </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a css units for the properties e.g. px, %, em's.

From this code,

```
style="min-height: 10; max-height: 10;overflow-y: scroll;"
```

it should be

```
style="min-height: 10px; max-height: 140px;overflow-y: scroll;"
```